# Swift: Como obtener datos de archivos en firebase Storage a una vista en swiftUI

Tags: firebase, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firestore, firebase-auth

necesito ayuda con un problema de programación en swift con el framework swiftUI. Se trata de una red social, en donde al principio te registras o inicias sesión, la autenticación es por medio de firebase, después  rellenas un formulario con tu nombre, foto, biografía entre otras cosas, y la información se envía a firebase y se almacena en firestore database, hasta ahí todo va bien, la autenticación funciona y los datos se almacenan correctamente con el modelo (MVVM), el problema es que no he encontrado la manera de una vez teniendo la información del usuario almacenada en Firestore,  llevar esa información una vista en la cual se muestre el perfil del usuario, alguien me podría decir como lograrlo por favor?

Soy nuevo en swift y todavia no le entiendo del todo, Pero agradeceria mucho cualquier sugerencia.

Aquí esta el modelo

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Firebase

// MARK: - User Model
struct FirebaseUserModel: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var coverImage: String
    var profileImage: String
    var username: String
    var name: String
    var age: String
    var description: String
    var gender: String
}
```

Aquí esta la clase FirebaseUserModel

```
class FirebaseViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var data = [FirebaseUserModel]()
    
    // MARK: - Save info
    func saveInfoUser(coverImage: Data, profileImage: Data, username: String, name: String, age: String, description: String, gender: String, completion: @escaping (_ done: Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        
        let profileImageIDName = UUID()
        let coverImageIDName = UUID()
        
        let directoryProfileImage = storage.child("ProfileImages/\(profileImageIDName)")
        let directoryCoverImage = storage.child("CoverImages/\(coverImageIDName)")
        
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        
        metadata.contentType = "image/png"
        
        directoryProfileImage.putData(profileImage, metadata: metadata) { data, error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Save profile photo correctly".uppercased())
            } else {
                if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                    print("Failed to save image to Storage", error)
                } else {
                    print("There was a bug in the app")
                }
            }
        }
        
        directoryCoverImage.putData(coverImage, metadata: metadata) { data, error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Cover photo saved successfully".uppercased())
            } else {
                if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                    print("Error saving cover photo to Storage", error)
                } else {
                    print("There was a bug in the app")
                }
            }
        }
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        
        guard let idUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
        
        let fields: [String: Any] = ["coverImage": String(describing: directoryCoverImage), "profileImage": String(describing: directoryProfileImage), "username": username, "name": name, "age": age, "description": description, "gender": gender, "idUser": idUser, "email": email]
        
        db.collection(name).document(id).setData(fields) { error in
            if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                print("Error saving to firestore".uppercased(), error)
            } else {
                print("Data saved successfully")
                completion(true)
            }
        }
                
    } // saveInfoUser
    
    // MARK: - Show user information
    func getData(name: String) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("name").addSnapshotListener { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                print("Error displaying user data", error)
            } else {
                self.data.removeAll()
                for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                    let value = document.data()
                    let id = document.documentID
                    let coverImage = value["coverImage"] as? String ?? "No cover image"
                    let profileImage = value["profileImage"] as? String ?? "No profile picture"
                    let username = value["username"] as? String ?? "No username"
                    let name = value["name"] as? String ?? "Unnamed"
                    let age = value["age"] as? String ?? "Ageless"
                    let description = value["description"] as? String ?? "Without description"
                    let gender = value["gender"] as? String ?? "Unknown gender"
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let records = FirebaseUserModel(id: id, coverImage: coverImage, profileImage: profileImage, username: username, name: name, age: age, description: description, gender: gender)
                        self.data.append(records)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } // getData

}
```

Quiero mostrar la información del usuario en esta vista de swiftUI, he intentado con varios tutoriales pero no logro traer los datos desde firebase. (Los datos ya están en el storage con toda la información y fotos del usuario).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Con un `StateObject` podes accesar el `FirebaseViewModel`

```
@StateObject var vm: FirebaseViewModel = FirebaseViewModel()
```

En una `View` que enseña una lista puedes sacar cada usuario.

```
ForEach(vm.data, id:\.id){ user in
    Text(user.name)
}
```

En to `AccountView` puedes agregar una variable

```
let user: FirebaseUserModel
```

y padres pasar cada usuario

```
AccountView(user: user)
```